# What errors can happen when encode with Swift JSONEncoder

Tags: swift, codable

`JSONEncoder` method `func encode<T>(_ value: T) throws -> Data where T : Encodable` is throwable.

I wonder why is it throwable: If the value to encode is not conform to `Encodable`, it can't pass compiler checking, so it should encounter no errors at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `JSONEncoder`'s [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L123):

```
/// - throws: `EncodingError.invalidValue` if a non-conforming floating-point value is encountered during encoding, and the encoding strategy is `.throw`.
/// - throws: An error if any value throws an error during encoding.
```

Debug descriptions for all errors:

> Top-level (T.self) did not encode any values.
>
> Top-level (T.self) encoded as null JSON fragment.
>
> Top-level (T.self) encoded as number JSON fragment.
>
> Top-level (T.self) encoded as string JSON fragment.